# Binding Gradient color in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, colors

I have to bind the gradient color property. In this I am using a converter. Here is the xaml code for binding

```
<GradientStop Color="{Binding Namevalue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource nametocolorconverter}}"/>
```

the code for nametocolorconverter

```
class nametocolorconverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       Brush brw = new Brush();
        if(value == "Blue") brw = Colors.Blue;
        elseif(value=="Green") brw = Colors.Green;
        else brw=Colors.Red;
   return brw;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

The above code is not working. I am not getting the desired color.

Comment: You changed `Namevalue`, but color wasn't changed?

Comment: Do you have resource with `nametocolorconverter` key? Similar to the following: `<l:nametocolorconverter x:Key="nametocolorconverter" />`.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Yes I have added it to the resource.

Comment: @user3449857: Yes, the color was not changed

Comment: @Amr When you debug, does the program enters `Convert` method? Is your color always red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not even compile.

In the Convert method you declare a local variable `brw` of type `Brush` and try to create a new `Brush` instance. Besides that this won't work because `Brush` is an abstract class, you should instead have a variable of type `Color`:

```
Color color;
if (value == "Blue")
{
    color = Colors.Blue;
}
else if (value == "Green")
{
    color = Colors.Green;
}
else
{
    color = Colors.Red;
}
```

You may also use a switch statement instead of an if-else chain:

```
switch ((string)value)
{
    case "Blue":
        color = Colors.Blue;
        break;
    case "Green":
        color = Colors.Green;
        break;
    default:
        color = Colors.Red;
        break;
}
```

Or even simpler, if you use only standard color names:

```
return (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString((string)value);
```

Comment: Yes you were right. I changed it to colors and it worked. Thanks :)